# Trying to filter a list into another list based on the value of an index

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create an app that will need to use the IMDb dataset. IMDb gives out datasets that have every title on IMDb, including tv shows and videogames. For example:

"tt9620292  movie   Promising Young Woman   Promising Young Woman   0   2020    \N  113 Crime,Drama,Thriller

tt1568322   videoGame   Batman: Arkham City Batman: Arkham City 0   2011    \N  \N  Action,Adventure,Crime

tt0141842   tvSeries    The Sopranos    The Sopranos    0   1999    2007    55  Crime,Drama"

I have read in the IMDb dataset and broken each line into a list, splitting them by tabs, which gives me a bunch of lists where index one of each list has the description of the title(movie, tvEpisode, short, videogame, etc.) The ultimate goal is to read in this IMDb dataset text file, then write to another file with only titles with the description of movie, tvMovie, or short. For now, I am printing out test lists to see if I can correctly filter out everything but movie, tvMovie and short titles.

Now I am stuck at a point where I can print out index one of each list, which only prints out the description of each title:[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jP6Zg.png)
but when I try to use the same list and index to populate another list with only movie, tvMovie and short titles, it fills the list with every title regardless.

```
IMDbFile = open("titleTest", "r")
lineList = IMDbFile.readlines()

listOfList = []
for x in lineList:
    listOfList.append(x.split("\t"))

movieOnly = []
for x in listOfList:
    if x[1] == "short" or "movie" or "tvMovie":
        movieOnly.append(x)
    #print(x[1])


for n in movieOnly:
    print(n)
IMDbFile.close()
```

When printing the "movieOnly" list, I get every title:[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpQk4.png)

Comment: This line is not going to work. ```if x[1] == "short" or "movie" or "tvMovie":movieOnly.append(x)``` Instead try this. ```if x[1] in  ("short","movie","tvMovie"):pass```

Comment: @BuddyBobIII that works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies in the way that you wrote the if statement. Instead of:

```
movieOnly = []
for x in listOfList:
    if x[1] == "short" or "movie" or "tvMovie":
        movieOnly.append(x)
```

try

```
movieOnly = []
for x in listOfList:
    if x[1] in ["short","movie","tvMovie"]:
        movieOnly.append(x)
```

The reason is that this:

```
if 'a' == 'b' or 'c' or 'd':
    print('here')
```

will print 'here' because

```
or 'c'
```

is evaluating if 'c' is True and not whether 'a'=='c'

Comment: this works for me, thanks! thanks for the explanation as well